# Separate PostgreSQL partitions join

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-10

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.6. I have several tables partitioned by day. Each day has its own data. I want to select rows from this tables within a day.

```
drop table IF EXISTS request;
drop table IF EXISTS request_identity;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request (
    id bigint not null,    
    record_date date not null,
    payload text not null
) PARTITION BY LIST (record_date);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_p1 PARTITION OF request FOR VALUES IN ('2001-01-01');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_p2 PARTITION OF request FOR VALUES IN ('2001-01-02');

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_request_p1_id ON request_p1 (id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_request_p2_id ON request_p2 (id);

do $$  
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    INSERT INTO  request (id,record_date,payload) values (i, '2001-01-01', 'abc');
  end loop;  
  for i in 100001..200000 loop
    INSERT INTO  request (id,record_date,payload) values (i, '2001-01-02', 'abc');
  end loop;
end;
$$;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_identity (
    record_date date not null,
    parent_id bigint NOT NULL,
    identity_name varchar(32),
    identity_value varchar(32)
) PARTITION BY LIST (record_date);   

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_identity_p1 PARTITION OF request_identity FOR VALUES IN ('2001-01-01');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_identity_p2 PARTITION OF request_identity FOR VALUES IN ('2001-01-02');

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_request_identity_p1_payload ON request_identity_p1 (identity_name, identity_value);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_request_identity_p2_payload ON request_identity_p2 (identity_name, identity_value);

do $$  
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    INSERT INTO  request_identity (parent_id,record_date,identity_name,identity_value) values (i, '2001-01-01', 'NAME', 'somename'||i);
  end loop;  
  for i in 100001..200000 loop
    INSERT INTO  request_identity (parent_id,record_date,identity_name,identity_value) values (i, '2001-01-02', 'NAME', 'somename'||i);
  end loop;
end;
$$;

analyze request;
analyze request_identity;
```

I make select inside 1 day and see a good request plan:

```
explain analyze select * 
    from request 
   where record_date between '2001-01-01' and '2001-01-01' 
   and exists (select * from request_identity where parent_id = id and identity_name = 'NAME' and identity_value = 'somename555' and record_date between '2001-01-01' and '2001-01-01')    
   limit 100;

Limit  (cost=8.74..16.78 rows=1 width=16)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.74..16.78 rows=1 width=16)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=8.45..8.46 rows=1 width=8)
              Group Key: request_identity_p1.parent_id
              ->  Append  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8)
                    ->  Index Scan using i_request_identity_p1_payload on request_identity_p1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8)
                          Index Cond: (((identity_name)::text = 'NAME'::text) AND ((identity_value)::text = 'somename555'::text))
                          Filter: ((record_date >= '2001-01-01'::date) AND (record_date <= '2001-01-01'::date))
        ->  Append  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=16)
              ->  Index Scan using i_request_p1_id on request_p1  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=16)
                    Index Cond: (id = request_identity_p1.parent_id)
                    Filter: ((record_date >= '2001-01-01'::date) AND (record_date <= '2001-01-01'::date))
```

But if I make a select for 2 days or more, then PostgreSQL first appends rows of all partitions of request_identity and all partitions of request, and then joins them.
So this is the SQL that is not working as i want:

```
explain analyze select * 
    from request 
   where record_date between '2001-01-01' and '2001-01-02' 
   and exists (select * from request_identity where parent_id = id and identity_name = 'NAME' and identity_value = 'somename1777' and record_date between '2001-01-01' and '2001-01-02')    
   limit 100;  

Limit  (cost=17.19..50.21 rows=2 width=16)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17.19..50.21 rows=2 width=16)
        ->  Unique  (cost=16.90..16.91 rows=2 width=8)
              ->  Sort  (cost=16.90..16.90 rows=2 width=8)
                    Sort Key: request_identity_p1.parent_id
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.42..16.89 rows=2 width=8)
                          ->  Index Scan using i_request_identity_p1_payload on request_identity_p1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8)
                                Index Cond: (((identity_name)::text = 'NAME'::text) AND ((identity_value)::text = 'somename1777'::text))
                                Filter: ((record_date >= '2001-01-01'::date) AND (record_date <= '2001-01-02'::date))
                          ->  Index Scan using i_request_identity_p2_payload on request_identity_p2  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8)
                                Index Cond: (((identity_name)::text = 'NAME'::text) AND ((identity_value)::text = 'somename1777'::text))
                                Filter: ((record_date >= '2001-01-01'::date) AND (record_date <= '2001-01-02'::date))
        ->  Append  (cost=0.29..16.63 rows=2 width=16)
              ->  Index Scan using i_request_p1_id on request_p1  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=16)
                    Index Cond: (id = request_identity_p1.parent_id)
                    Filter: ((record_date >= '2001-01-01'::date) AND (record_date <= '2001-01-02'::date))
              ->  Index Scan using i_request_p2_id on request_p2  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=16)
                    Index Cond: (id = request_identity_p1.parent_id)
                    Filter: ((record_date >= '2001-01-01'::date) AND (record_date <= '2001-01-02'::date))
```

In my case it doesn't make sense to join (with nested loops) of these appends since the consistent rows are only within 1 day partitions group.

The desired result for me is that PostgreSQL makes joins between request_p1 to request_identity_p1, and request_p2 to request_identity_p2 first and only after that is makes appends of results.

The question is:

Is there a way to perform joins between partitions separately within 1 day partitions group?

Thanks.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: With PostgreSQL v12, you could try setting `enable_partitionwise_join = on`.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL v10.6

Comment: Why do you partition using LIST when your key is time? You should use RANGE which should properly 'key in' the query planner that it should prune partitions before a join, furthermore, if the days are a known you can also do a Direct join using partition names such as request_identity_y2020m08d01 and request_identity_y2020m08d02